# Connect GeoServer to MongoDB

Tags: geoserver, mongodb

I'm new to this GIS stuff and I've already got the MongoDB extension working, added a database to GeoServer (2.15.1) store and even managed to add a layer and recognizing the document structure (it's a GeoJSON). However, the map is showing as empty. I also added a PostGIS layer just to be sure and that one works like a charm. Here's an image showing the structure GeoServer identifies:

[image: Here's an image showing the structure GeoServer identifies]

When I Open the layer Preview this happens (code="internalError"Rendering process failed
BasicBSONList can only work with numeric keys not: [type]):
[image]

Any Idea why even if I added a layer it's not showing anything? As anyone managed to succesfully connect MongoDB and GeoServer?

EDIT: Here's a the mongoDB JSON example (taken from compass)
type:"Feature" 
properties:Object
      id:667881
      Categoría:"Almacenes y bodegas"
      nom_estab:"BODEGA DE LA DIRECCIÓN DE PARQUES Y JARDÍNES DE LA DELEGACIÓN AZCAPOTZ..."
      raz_social:"DELEGACIÓN AZCAPOTZALCO"
      codigo_act:931210
      per_ocu:"11 a 30 personas"
      tipo_vial:"CALLE"
      nom_vial:"PRIMERA PRIVADA RECREO"
      tipo_v_e_1:"CERRADA"
     nom_v_e_1:"SEGUNDA CAMARONES"
      tipo_v_e_2:"CALLE"
      nom_v_e_2:"CAMINO DEL RECREO"
      tipo_v_e_3:"CALLE"
      nom_v_e_3:"TERCERA PRIVADA RECREO"
      numero_ext:656
      letra_ext:null
      edificio:null
      edificio_e:null
      numero_int:null
      letra_int:null
      tipo_asent:"COLONIA"
      nomb_asent:"EL RECREO"
      tipocencom:null
      nom_cencom:null
      num_local:null
      cod_postal:2070
      cve_ent:9
      entidad:"Ciudad de México"
      cve_mun:2
      municipio:"Azcapotzalco"
      cve_loc:1
      localidad:"Azcapotzalco"
      ageb:"472"
      manzana:7
      telefono:null
      correoelec:null
      www:null
      tipounieco:"Fijo"
      latitud:19.47592545
      longitud:-99.18356323
      fecha_alta:"dic-14"
    geometry:Object
type:"Point"
    coordinates:Array
      0:-99.18356323
      1:19.47592545

Comment: please add the **text** of the JSON schema and an example feature.

Comment: There, I added a Json example taken from compass of what's in there. It's a geoJson, not much to show there